# Include wxWidgets (3.1.1) installed with msys 2 into our project, using cmake

Tags: cmake, wxwidgets, clion, msys2

We are trying to include and make wxWidgets run in our project.
We are using CMake to compile and to include our libraries with msys2. We are using CLion as IDE. After several days of testing, we are still unable to make it run. There are way too many and different errors to post all of them. 
I think we have tried everything you can possible do, read everything you can possible read, but it still won't work.

We also tried to install the whole wxWidget.zip Folder and implement everything by path, still nothing.

There are some posts about this issue, but nothing seems to work.

My question, is there anybody who encountered the same problem and fixed that? Is there a step by step guide to implement everything correctly?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Show us first error.

Comment: Hey, this is what I get when I implement from msys2

find_package(wxWidget REQUIRED)


Could not find a package configuration file provided by "wxWidget" with any of the following names:
wxWidgetConfig.cmake

or 

 Could NOT find wxWidgets (missing: wxWidgets_LIBRARIES
  wxWidgets_INCLUDE_DIRS)
wxwidget-config.cmake

Comment: I cannot see here any error message

Comment: When i am including the path to the wxWidget folder:
 C:/Users/usr/Downloads/wxWidgets-3.1.1/include

Its compiling but I get some other errors like:

C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lwxWidgets

or  error "wxUSE_ACTIVEX must be defined."

Comment: So compiler is unable to find libraries. I'm not sure how it works under Windows but I guess all necessary libraries need to be in PATH.

Comment: We tried that aswell, does not seem to work either. Maybe using cmake is not the best when it comes to wxWidgets.

Comment: It has nothing to do with cmake. Problem is in your environment. Also make sure you have libraries prepared for your compiler.

Comment: I think we did everything the way it should be. But thanks for your time. I guess it's time for me to try something else, as I already spent way too much time trying to find a way.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Here we use comments for "temporary" things, like requests for clarifications about the question. As for code and error message, they should be in the **questions post itself**. Please, [edit] your question post, and add the code and the error messages into it. Both code and error messages could be formatted (while selected) with `Ctrl+K` or `{}` button.

Comment: @MortenSteitz, CMake work for wxWidgets is still WIP. Now, here is my questions: 1. How did you build the libraries under MSYS? 2. Can you build the 'minimal' sample provided with the library? Keep in mind that just installing wxWidgets.zip is not enough - you have to build the libraries using the compiler you have as described in different places and particularly in the documentation.

Comment: @MortenSteitz, the best way is to open MSYS, and then do: "cd c:/Users/usr/Downloads/wxWidgets-3.1.1 && mkdir buildMSYS && cd buildMSYS && ../configure --with-msw && make". For that you should have to have a compiler (MinGW{32,64} to be visible (on your PATH). After you build wxWidgets, try to build and run 'minimal' sample provided inside wxWidgets/samples/minimal. I don't work with MSYS, but I think you should do this: "cd C:/Users/usr/Downloads/wxWidgets-3.1.1/buildMSYS/samples/minimal && make && ./minimal". If its successful, try to build you project again.

Comment: @Igor Thanks, I will try that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the current msys2 version of wxwidgets does not work correctly (FindCMake file not working + different folder names for include than in the docs on the wxWidgets homepage), I suggest the following workaround:

1. [Download wxWidgets](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets/releases/download/v3.1.1/wxWidgets-3.1.1.7z) and unpack it to a directory of your choice.
2. Run CLion (and build wxWidgets the following way):

   - Close any open project and do `Import Projetct from Sources`.
   - Select the directory you unzipped wxWidgets into.
   - Select `Use existing CMakeLists.txt`
   - After CMake finished loading - Build the project (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F9</kbd>). I recommend using *release* mode.
3. After building wxWidgets finished in CLion, there is a new folder called 'cmake-build-release' or 'cmake-build-debug'. If you would like to integrate the wxWidgets built into your project, I suggest:

   - copy all `.a`-files from /lib/gcc_dll/ to a new project folder,
   - copy all `.dll` files from /lib/gcc_dll/ to your project build folder
   - copy the include folder from the original wxWidgets archive to your project and **in any case** copy the `setup.h` from /lib/gcc_dll/mswud/wx/ to the include folder as well.
4. Edit your project's CMakeLists.txt:

   - To your `include_directories` add the path to the wxWidgets `include` folder
   - To your `target_link_libraries` add the path of **every** `.a` file.

In my case point 4 resulted in the following lines to make it crystal clear:

```
include_directories(
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cpp/libs/wx_headers/include
        )
```

and

```
target_link_libraries(example_project
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cpp/libs/wx_build/libwxbase31u.a
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cpp/libs/wx_build/libwxbase31u_net.a
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cpp/libs/wx_build/libwxbase31u_xml.a
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cpp/libs/wx_build/libwxexpat.a
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cpp/libs/wx_build/libwxjpeg.a
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cpp/libs/wx_build/libwxmsw31u_adv.a
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cpp/libs/wx_build/libwxmsw31u_aui.a
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cpp/libs/wx_build/libwxmsw31u_core.a
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cpp/libs/wx_build/libwxmsw31u_gl.a
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cpp/libs/wx_build/libwxmsw31u_html.a
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cpp/libs/wx_build/libwxmsw31u_media.a
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cpp/libs/wx_build/libwxmsw31u_propgrid.a
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cpp/libs/wx_build/libwxmsw31u_qa.a
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cpp/libs/wx_build/libwxmsw31u_ribbon.a
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cpp/libs/wx_build/libwxmsw31u_richtext.a
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cpp/libs/wx_build/libwxmsw31u_stc.a
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cpp/libs/wx_build/libwxmsw31u_webview.a
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cpp/libs/wx_build/libwxmsw31u_xrc.a
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cpp/libs/wx_build/libwxpng.a
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cpp/libs/wx_build/libwxregexu.a
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cpp/libs/wx_build/libwxscintilla.a
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cpp/libs/wx_build/libwxtiff.a
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cpp/libs/wx_build/libwxzlib.a
)
```

DISCLAIMER:

You should know, that including libraries that way is considered bad practise and as soon as MSYS2 supplies a wxWidgets library with a working `find_package`-file use that instead!

Comment: @MortenSteitz If it fixed your problem you should accept the answer.

Comment: @Justin, you don't have to copy the resulting dll/a files and header files anywhere. Just point everything into the original place where the build was done. It is much simpler and saves time. Also building the library in `debug` mode will save time in a long run - so I'd recommend that instead. Also, keep in mind that `CMake` for wxWidgets is WIP ATM. You can try it - but the official way of building is still through the `configure + make`

Comment: @MortenSteitz, please see my comment above.

Comment: @Igor I admit your way is cleaner, but it doesn't work with MSYS2 on Windows out of the box ( ../configure --with-msw will throw errors more complex than your suggestion of just pointing PATH to a compiler).

Comment: @Igor I was just pointing out to the OP (since they seem relatively new to the site) that accepting an answer that solves their problem is better than comments that say 'thanks it worked'. If you have a better solution than the one posted, it may be worth creating your own answer.

Comment: @Igor And "*Just point everything into the original place where the build was done*" might involve absolute paths, which would make the CMakeLists.txt obsolete, when you want to open the project on a different machine.

Comment: @nada, what errors will be thrown? what compiler did you use to produce them? and why do you want to open the project on the different machine? development is usually (99% of the time) is done on the same machine it started. and finally, I'm curious - what is dependent on the debug build of the library?

Comment: @Igor Ok, first, well following your instructions (setting up gcc in path) I get that X11 is missing. I know that is manageable, but building with CMake takes zero user configuration and just works. Second: 99%? Source please. And third: When you want to compile a finished product, you'd use a release build mode. Debug mode sometimes gives more helpful error messages, which would be the recommended setting during development.

Comment: @nada, `We are trying to include and make wxWidgets run in our project.`. I believe this very first sentence from the OP constitutes as a development stage.

Comment: @nada, you tried `../configure --with-msw` and you got an error about X11? What is the exact error message? Is it from configure or make?

Comment: @nada, if you are working for a company you have you development environment set as a standard one from either an ISO, a ghost machine backup or a VM. And so every machine has everything set up for you from one initial setup. And even in the small companies people are using Source Control software to pass the projects from one machine to another. And so yes, I believe that my number is correct.

Comment: @Igor It seems we could go on forever, so I suggest as Justin just suggested to just describe your way of doing things in a separate answer.

Comment: @nada, don't need to, since this one worked for the OP. But since you are getting the error with simple configure line I'd suggest to report it to the wx-dev ML, on `trac.wxwidgets.org` or create an issue on wxWidgets GitHub site. That way it can be fixed. I can't do that as I don't have your environment and therefore couldn't replicate the problem. You will help improve the library by reporting it. As I said `configure + make` is an official way of building and if it doesn't work - its a bug.

Answer (score 0):

The core problem is the wx library installed by pacman in msys2 is build from "make", which is a unix like shell, which has different folder structure compared with the native windows mingw build wx.

Under Msys2, to generate the mingw style makefile from cmake, you have to hack the cmake file: <msys2_root>\mingw64\share\cmake-3.17\Modules\FindwxWidgets.cmake

Here is the detail:

[Re: Using wxWidgets with Win10, msys2, mingw64 and CLion](https://forums.wxwidgets.org/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=47555#p202984)

After that, you can correctly use the mingw style makefile.

**EDIT** 2022-04-30, msys2's cmake now can correctly find wx library, see my tutorials here:

https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/issues/11585#issuecomment-1113904778